# Call hooks after the main delayed job completed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I have been using delayed_job_active_record gem in my application, in one of my use-case i have to use one hook to send an other email after the delayed job done. https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#hooks, how can i override that in my application?.

Currently i am calling in this way

```
do_maintenance.delay(run_at: time).change_all_parts(batch_no)
```

do_maintenance is the model

Answer (score 0):

Hooks from this gem provide callbacks to the job, but not to the model. But you can define custom callback in the model. That callback will be called after the delayed method:

```
class DoMaintenance < ApplicationRecord
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks

  define_model_callbacks :change_all_parts, :only => [:after]

  after_change_all_parts :notify

  def change_all_parts
    run_callbacks :change_all_parts do
      #your delayed method
    end
  end
  handle_asynchronously :change_all_parts

  def notify
    #your code
  end
end
```